# Using f2py get ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, fortran, pycharm, f2py

I'm trying to create python module on Pycharm. i did this

`f2py -c area.f90 -m AREA`

the module was created but the module file(AREAmodule) was not built so when i import and run it show the error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Does anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Could you also post the code that calls the module?

Comment: Try updating to 2019.2.3. Do you use Anaconda?

Comment: @rammelmueller 
i've changed all the code by using this code for making the module
https://pastebin.com/d5ye9Jeb
and follow the step from this website http://lagrange.univ-lyon1.fr/docs/numpy/1.11.0/f2py/usage.html 
Then i found the website that can generate the module by using simple command in Python. just like this 
https://pastebin.com/2zXCWpWB
May i can ask you about the different between the two methods ?

Comment: @PavelKarateev 
i follow the step of making the module from this website 
http://lagrange.univ-lyon1.fr/docs/numpy/1.11.0/f2py/usage.html 
They didn't using Anaconda
but i've found that so many people who work on F2py they sometimes mention to Anaconda. Does it important to use it ? i'm a very beginner about coding you can correct me if i get anything's wrong

Answer (score 1):

For me the dll is created in the sub directory `module_name\.libs\libmodule_namexxxxx.dll`, when I copy it to my source directory, It works!!!.

You can check for the dependency in the module via `depends.exe`, I load my module in `depends`, it automatically tells me I need those dll.